# django - show objects of a single user

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of assets, created by different users. I'd like to show the assets for **each** user in a template.

Right now, I have this (there's more code, but not relevant for this issue):

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models
class Asset(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     description = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
     dateadded = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
     file = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', verbose_name='Image', null=True, blank=True)
     url = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True, default='')
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Asset
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def assets(request):
    assets = Asset.objects
    users = User.objects
    context = {'assets':assets, 'users':users}
    return render(request, 'assets/assets.html', context)
```

But what should I put in my **template**? The following gives a list of all assets, but the second part should only show assets by 'bob' and eventually all assets listed by user (all assets by 'bob, all assets by 'pete', etc) regardless of the user being signed in.

```
{% for asset in assets.all %}
{% if asset.file %}
{{ asset.dateadded_pretty }} - <a href="{% url 'detail' asset.id %}">{{ asset.title }}</a> <span style="font-size:11px">
  ({{ asset.ext }} - {{ asset.size }})</span>
{% else %}
{{ asset.dateadded_pretty }} - <a href="{% url 'detail' asset.id %}">{{ asset.title }}</a> <span style="font-size:11px">
  (external link)</span>
{% endif %}
<br>
{% endfor %}
<br><br><br>
Assets by Bob:

{% for asset in assets.all %}

{% if asset.user == "bob" %}
{{ user.title}}
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First query all the users in view

```
def assets(request):
    assets = Asset.objects.all()
    users = User.objects.all()
    context = {'assets':assets, 'users':users}
```

**EDIT:** you can filter the users who has assets like this.

```
users = User.objects.filter(id__in=assets)
```

Now in the template you can do like this to get the assets by individual user

```
{% for user in users %}
{{user.email}}
{% for asset in user.asset_set.all %}
{{ asset.title}}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, but this gives an error: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.

Comment: great! getting there :-) Obvs, this repeats the the user for each asset. What I'd really like is having the user mentioned once, and then a list of all of her/his assets... .
EDIT: just moving {{ user.email }} up in the first for loop does the trick. I shows all the users, including the ones with no assets, but I think I can solve that with an {% if %}.

Comment: You can do this in your view. Check the answer @Thomas

Comment: thank you so much, hours of frustrations just vanished :-)